Resources for academics who want to write an op-ed?
Sometimes professors write op-eds. This is appropriate, for example, if the professor's research expertise and published work(s) are relevant to some timely topic in the news, and can reasonably be communicated to the general public. I find myself in such a situation, but have no experience whatsoever writing op-eds. Are there resources for professors seeking to develop in this direction? Or a discussion somewhere of the pros and cons of this kind of outreach?
For context, I am a tenured math professor based in the USA. The op-ed would be based on a paper I recently published in Crime Science. The point would be to explain what the data says regarding actions of police and the resulting impact on the dynamics of protests and the violence of protests. This is obviously a politically sensitive topic, hence my desire to "get it right" if I move in this direction. There have been a couple of previous questions about outreach as part of the career of a professor:
How important is outreach for applying to tenure track professor position?
Invitation for science outreach - any downsides?
Mathematicians don't really have training on this kind of thing.

A good starting point would be to use acquaintances and family members as guinea pigs on drafts. See how they react, whether they get the message, or whether you need to keep working on getting the message right and across.

I vaguely recall reading an article a few years ago with advice for mathematicians writing op-eds.  Possibly in AMS Notices or something like that.  Unfortunately I can't find it now.

@NateEldredge Do you think it was this one? http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/media-info/communicate-math

As this question is closed, I cannot add what I learned over the past 13 days about writing op-eds. But, I can share that, I was able to successfully write one and get it published: https://www.nydailynews.com/2024/05/16/cooperation-can-end-violent-protests/

Congratulations and it is an excellent article! Could you give us just a few short sentences about what you learned ?

It's essential to get the piece in front of the right editor. Networking is critical. Newspapers are more likely to accept op-eds from authors who have published one previously. Timing is key. Link to recent news stories and local events in the place where your target newspaper is located. Advocate to be considered quickly while remaining polite. Have lots of friends read it. They can suggest more connections. Explain the research in the simplest possible terms. Show it to non-experts. Rewrite it over and over again to hone the message. Strong opening; kicker to end it, call back to opening.

This might be useful. It is not for academics in particular, but for non-journalists.
https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/2022/op-ed-writing-guide-washington-post-examples/

Thanks! That was very helpful

Scholars Strategy Network runs trainings on this sort of thing:
https://scholars.org/
Your university may as well.

Thanks! I looked at it.
